# need the script for back button emulation

Tags: android

can someone tell me what script/command I need to run on a rooted phone to emulate android's hardware back button?

I'm trying to create a always-on-screen back button and its code is all set. Now I'm looking for a script/command which can emulate android's hardware back key press and set it to whatever app is active. something like http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=9575198 and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=865525

What i'm looking would be a shell command like "su event_command back_key_code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call:

`finish();`

It will kill the current activity and remove it from the stack returning the user to the previous activity. Much like the back button does.

Comment: I'm sorry but what I'm looking is very different and system-level. I'v added details in OP

Answer (score -1):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sendevent /dev/input/event3 1 158 1")
```

158  is the value of the back button in android

something like this should work although not tested of course you need to ask for root first